# Laravel 5.2 AUtomatic compute

Tags: jquery, laravel

How to automatically compute for the manager fee and total fee on keypress.

```
<input type="text" id="paid_to_you" name="paid_to_you" value="" style="width: 105px;">
<label id='manager_fee'></label>
<label id='total_fee'></label>
```

WHen the user inputs 1000, it will compute for the manager fee with a 10% of the input 'paid to you'.

Here's my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('input').change(function(e)  {
    var total_fee = 0;
    var paid_to_you = parseFloat($('#paid_to_you').html());
    var manager_fee = parseFloat($('#manager_fee').html());
    total_fee = (paid_to_you+manager_fee) * .10;
    $('#total_fee').html( total_fee);
});
```

});

Comment: where is your jquery?

Comment: @madalinivascu i have posted my jquery

Comment: #paid_to_you is input use .val()

Comment: @Neha stil nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to bind specific input

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#paid_to_you').bind('input', function(){
  var total_fee = 0;

  var paid_to_you = parseFloat($('#paid_to_you').val());
  var manager_fee = parseFloat($('#manager_fee').html());

   if(isNaN(manager_fee)) manager_fee =0;
  var total_fee = (paid_to_you+manager_fee) * .10;

  $('#total_fee').html(""+ total_fee);
});
});
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxgtwhj9/)

Comment: @samantha.nicole I cant tell until u share more info. Like whats happen when u enter text in input,, does method get call? put alert/console.log to see what u getting into paid_to_you var?  also more specifics what exact is not working? is there any error in inspect element?

Comment: It's working. Thank you. I just noticed my error in my controller that's why this code dont work. Thank you. :)

Comment: Good .. :) no prob.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you have said

> WHen the user inputs 1000, it will compute for the manager fee with a
>   10% of the input 'paid to you'.

So, `manager_fee` should be `100` and `total_fee` should be `1100`.
Use this

```
$('input').change(function(e) {
    var total_fee = 0;
    var paid_to_you = parseFloat($('#paid_to_you').val());
    var manager_fee = paid_to_you * .10;
    total_fee = (paid_to_you+manager_fee);
    $('#manager_fee').text(manager_fee);
    $('#total_fee').text(total_fee);
});
```

Comment: It's still not woking. What am i missing out? :(